# SSIS - move only the files names returned in SQL command

Tags: ssis

I have a SQL statement that returns 600 PDF filenames that I need to use to move a copy of the file out of folder into a new folder (The filenames in the SQL are the exact name of the PDF files in the folder).

I have a execute SQL statement set up that passes the PDF name result set to a variable.

How can I use this variable to pass to file system task to only copy out the PDF filenames returned in SQL statement and passed to variable?

Thanks,

Also I am getting an eror

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should tell us what it is. What's the error code and description text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty simple design pattern in SSIS. Generally speaking, you'll get your list of file names from an `Execute SQL Task`, set up a `Foreach Loop Container` to process each file, and a `File System Task` inside the loop.

To start, you'll want to make sure you have the following variables:

[image: VariablesList]

I'm using `E:\Import\` as my source folder. That's where I expect all my files to be. You can change this to be the folder where your files are. I want to move files into a subfolder, so I've set the `DestinationFolder` to `E:\Import\Internal\`. Again, change this to suit your needs.

Additionally, you can see we have a `Filenames` variable of type `System.Object`. This is the ADO object that will hold the results of our SQL query. The `Filename` string variable will be used to store each file name as we go through the loop.

`SourcePath` and `DestinationPath` we're going to configure to be populated by an expression. We're going to concatenate the folder names with our file names. To do that, open the variables window, and click on `SourcePath`. Then edit the `Properties` and set `EvaluateAsExpression` to `True`, and then set the expression to be `@[User::SourceFolder] + @[User::Filename]`. Do the same for `DestinationPath`, using the `@[User::DestinationFolder]` variable in the expression. You should end up with your two `*Path` variables looking something like this:
[image: SourcePath]
[image: SourcePathExpression]
[image: DestinationPath]
[image: DestinationPathExpression]

Now we can configure the `Execute SQL Task`. Make sure you set the `ResultSet` value to `Full result set` and map the results with `Result Name` equal to `0` to your ADO object variable `Filenames`.
[image: ExecuteSQL]
[image: ResultSet]

Next, create a `Foreach Loop Container` and configure it to use the `Foreach ADO Enumerator` type and point it to your `Filenames` variable.
[image: Foreach]

Go to `Variable Mappings` and make sure to map `User::Filename` to `Index 0`.
[image: ForeachVarMap]

Finally, create a `File System Task` and put it inside the loop container. Then configure it to use your `*Path` variables with the appropriate action.
[image: FST]

When you're all done, you should having a package that looks like this:
[image: FinalPackage]

Comment: Thank you!. it worked great. only thing missing was the +"\\"+ between the Folder paths and file names

Comment: Thats very well explained. Thanks